# Spring user admin sample

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty, spring-data

I'm trying to run the example of Spring LDAP [User Admin Sample (the official example)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples/user-admin)

> To run the example, do gradle jettyRun, or mvn jetty:run, and then
>   navigate to http://localhost:8080/spring-ldap-user-admin-sample

When I do `mvn jetty:run`, I get an error.

```
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.15.v20140411:run (default-cli) @ spring-ldap-user-admin-sample ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: spring-ldap-user-admin-sample
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Defaulting to C:\tmp_projects\spring-ldap-master\spring-ldap-master\samples\user-admin\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\tmp_projects\spring-ldap-master\spring-ldap-master\samples\user-admin\target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /spring-ldap-user-admin-sample
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\tmp_projects\spring-ldap-master\spring-ldap-master\samples\user-admin\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/C:/tmp_projects/spring-ldap-master/spring-ldap-master/samples/user-admin/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\tmp_projects\spring-ldap-master\spring-ldap-master\samples\user-admin\src\main\webapp
[INFO] jetty-8.1.15.v20140411
[INFO] No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
[INFO] No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[INFO] Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22:51:59.410 [main] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
22:51:59.541 [main] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat May 20 22:51:59 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
22:51:59.584 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
22:52:00.453 [main] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/config/EmbeddedValueResolver
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.<init>(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:72) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
```

[Full output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3409114c84770c10fd4dc32072614973)

I did not change anything in the files.

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the demo application successully compile? The exception is saying the Spring library is missing.

Comment: @MinhKieu Yes, it is successfully compile [log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb3a390e1f79a46d86966e89fb07f1dc). Can you check this sample? (download and run)

Comment: I just forked the entire project...It has a mixsture of Gradle and Maven...let me have a play and see what I can find out...from the first go...mvn clean install download lots of Spring dependencies.

Comment: @MinhKieu Well I'll wait. It would be very cool if you could start the project. :)

Comment: I am building the user-admin sample project and it complains about not finding the dependency "org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-test:jar:2.2.0.RC1". Do you have that issue?

Comment: @MinhKieu Hm, no. Maven compiles project successfully. Maybe you did not turn on auto-import in maven?

Comment: no, I need to install the "org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-test:jar:2.2.0.RC1" project to my local .m2 repository. However, I am searching the test folder but couldn't find such project. Let me do a grep!!!

Comment: I got passed Spring classNotFoundException by adding <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency> however I am now running into java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: @MinhKieu [spring-ldap-test:jar:2.2.0.RC1](http://rgho.st/85yks9pRZ); [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/P0k6rgO.png)

Comment: I think 2.2.0.RC1 has been removed. I am using 2.2.1.RELEASE and it worked. Still I need to resolve NoSuchMethodError as communicated earlier.

Comment: @MinhKieu Did you succeed?

Comment: getting close...I changed the jetty plugin...it seems to not include Spring in it classpath.

Comment: got it working @see answer section and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Add the below section to your pom.xml.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-framework-bom -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't help. Can you provide full `pom.xml` file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-ldap-user-admin-sample</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0.RC1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>spring-ldap-user-admin-sample</name>
  <description>spring-ldap-user-admin-sample</description>
  <url>http://www.springframework.org/ldap</url>
  <organization>
    <name>SpringSource</name>
    <url>http://springsource.org/</url>
  </organization>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>rwinch</id>
      <name>Rob Winch</name>
      <email>rwinch@gopivotal.com</email>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>marthursson</id>
      <name>Mattias Hellborg Arthursson</name>
      <email>mattias@261consulting.com</email>
      <organization>261 Consulting</organization>
      <organizationUrl>http://www.261consulting.com</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>ulsa</id>
      <name>Ulrik Sandberg</name>
      <email>ulrik.sandberg@jayway.com</email>
      <organization>Jayway</organization>
      <organizationUrl>http://www.jayway.com</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <contributors>
    <contributor>
      <name>Eric Dalquist</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Marius Scurtescu</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Tim Terry</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Keith Barlow</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Paul Harvey</name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
      <name>Marvin S. Addison</name>
    </contributor>
  </contributors>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-ldap</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-ldap</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-ldap</url>
  </scm>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>15.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-ldap-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-framework-bom -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snasphot</id>
      <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
        <configuration>
      <war>${project.basedir}/target/spring-ldap-user-admin-sample-2.2.0.RC1.war</war>
          <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/spring-ldap-user-admin-sample</contextPath>
          </webAppConfig>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Did you run application by `mvn jetty:run`?

Comment: Yes, the command as described in readme.md. This is the command I ran:  `mvn jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active=no-apacheds -Dsample.ldap.url=ldaps://127.0.0.1:636 \
     -Dsample.ldap.userDn=CN=ldaptest,CN=Users,DC=261consulting,DC=local -Dsample.ldap.password=secret \
     -Dsample.ldap.base=ou=test,dc=261consulting,dc=local -Dsample.ldap.directory.type=AD`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/issues/466) on the issue to get the user-admin sample project to start. I am still working on a solution to actual get the project working.